# To Create Dictionary By Passing One OutPut Of One Value to Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
Basic_Sal = (2750,2500,2900)// This is My Input
    for sal in Basic_Sal:
    if sal <= 2750:
        HRA = (sal*15)/100
        DA = (sal*10)/100
        MA = (sal *5)/100
        Gross_Sal = HRA + DA + MA //Here I am calculating Gross_Sal
        print(Gross_Sal)
    else:
        HRA = (sal * 20) / 100
        DA = (sal * 10) / 100
        MA = (sal * 5) / 100
        Gross_Sal = HRA + DA + MA
        print(Gross_Sal)
```

// I should get O/P as Dictionary =(Basic_Sal : Gross_Sal)

//Now I need to create Dictionary by passing Tuples and Gross_Sal, So that If I Call the Tuples I should get the Gross_salary directly. 
// Can Anyone Help me this Without Using Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Gross Salary based on salary, you should be saving your results in dictionary like this:

```
salaryDictionary = dict()
Basic_Sal = (2750,2500,2900)// This is My Input
for sal in Basic_Sal:
    if sal <= 2750:
        HRA = (sal*15)/100
        DA = (sal*10)/100
        MA = (sal *5)/100
        Gross_Sal = HRA + DA + MA //Here I am calculating Gross_Sal
        print(Gross_Sal)
    else:
        HRA = (sal * 20) / 100
        DA = (sal * 10) / 100
        MA = (sal * 5) / 100
        Gross_Sal = HRA + DA + MA
        print(Gross_Sal)
    salaryDictionary[sal] = Gross_Sal
```

Then you can call `salaryDictionary[sal]` and get the value. (first checking `if sal in salaryDictionary`)